# Every vector bundle can be induced from a principal bundle? its frame bundle?

Tags: algebraic-topology

If it is a theorem could somebody tell me the name? If it is wrong could somebody give a counterexample to illustrate what the obstruction is?

I am wondering this because in Clifford Taubes' book on differential geometry (Oxford GTM023) pp.134 the definition of connection and covariant derivative on vector bundles are defined for those induced from principal bundles i.e. the total space is of the form $E = P \times_{\rho} V$ where $\rho$ is a representation of $G$ on $V$.  I wonder whether this definition works for general vector bundles or not, which would not be an issue if every vector bundle can be induced from some principal bundle.

Thank you very much for your attention!

**PS**: in the comment below there is suggestion that every vector bundle can be induced by its frame bundle.  That amounts to showing $(E_{GL} \times V)/GL(V) \cong E$ where the frame bundle $E_{GL}$ is constructed by using the same clutching functions but modifying the local trivialization from $U_{\alpha} \times V$ to $U_{\alpha} \times GL(V)$.  In short the following operations are reverse to each other
\begin{equation}
  \text{vector bundle $E \to B$} \xrightarrow[U_{\alpha}\times V \to U_{\alpha} \times GL(V)]{E \leftarrow (E_{GL} \times V)/GL(V)} \text{frame bundle $E_{GL} \to B$}
\end{equation}
However I cannot see why $(E_{GL} \times V)/GL(V) \cong E$.  Could somebody show it is true or false?

Comment: Do you have some restriction on what sort of group G is or can we choose that to be as trivial as we want?

Comment: Take a covering $\lbrace U_i\rbrace$ that trivializes $V$.  $V$ is constructed by patching maps $f_{ij}:U_i\cap U_j\rightarrow GL_n$. You can use exactly the same maps to construct a bundle with $GL_n$ as the fiber and can check that this is a principal bundle that induces $V$.

Comment: If $E$ is an $n$-plane bundle over $M$, let $P = \{(m\in M, b$ is a basis of $E|_m)\}$, a principal $GL(n)$-bundle. This is a wholly standard construction, the "frame bundle".

Comment: There seems to be some confusion between "induced from" and "associated to". Usually the former is reserved for bundles obtained by taking a pullback, while the latter is reserved for fibre bundles formed from principal bundles by taking the Borel construction of your group acting on some space (as in the question).

Comment: @Mark: bear with me for the nonstandard terminology but I want to avoid the meaning of "associated to" for the frame bundle of a vector bundle.  Or are they actually the same thing (please see the "PS" above)?

Comment: @PhysicsMath: Yes, a vector bundle with fibre $V$ is isomorphic to the fibre bundle with fibre $V$ associated to its principal frame bundle. See Husemoller's "Fibre Bundles" book (in particular Definition 5.1 in Chapter 4 for the definition of fibre bundle, then Sections 1 to 3 in Chapter 5 for a proof of this claim).

Comment: There may be better references. The Wiki page is fairly explicit: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_bundle#Associated_vector_bundles

Comment: @Mark: Cool!  Thanks a lot for pointing out these very useful references to me!

Answer (score 1):

Let $\pi\colon E \to X$ be a vector bundle. Let $Fr(E)$ be the *frame bundle* whose fibre over a point $x\in X$ is the space of isomorphisms $Iso(\mathbb{R}^n, E_x)$. Pre-composition defines a right action of $GL_n$ on $Fr(E)$ making it a principal $GL_n$-bundle over $X$. Let $\tilde{E} = (Fr(E)\times \mathbb{R}^n)/GL_n$ be the Borel construction, i.e. the set of equivalence classes of pairs $[\varphi,v]$ where $[\varphi A,v] = [\varphi, Av]$ for every $A\in GL_n$.

Now there is a natural evaluation map $e\colon \tilde{E} \to E$ given by

$$e([\varphi, v]) = \varphi(v).$$

To construct an inverse for $e$, first choose for each $x\in X$ a frame $\varphi_x\in Fr(E)_x$ (this choice doesn't need to be continuous.) Now define

$$e^{-1}(p) = [\varphi_{\pi(x)}, \varphi_{\pi(x)}^{-1}(p)]$$

The well-definedness of $e$ and $e^{-1}$ follow from the definition of the Borel construction (you should write down the details for yourself), and since they are mutually inverse they are both bijections. The only gritty part is showing that they're continuous, which you can do pointwise inside a chart (you'll have to use the fact that in general evaluation maps $C(X, Y)\times X \to Y$ are continuous).